# How can I add line under Row of UICollectionView, Swift 5, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I add line under Row of UICollectionView, Swift 5, Xcode?

I want separate row by line. 
[image: CollectionView with CollectionViewCell and in right side running on emulator.]

Answer (score 4):

1. As Ayazmon said, you can add UIView to you cell with height of 1.
2. You can add bottom border to your cell.

   ```
   extension CALayer {

   func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

       let border = CALayer()

       switch edge {
       case .top:
           border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
       case .bottom:
           border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - thickness, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
       case .left:
           border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
       case .right:
           border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
       default:
           break
       }
       border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
       addSublayer(border)
       }
   }
   ```

Then

`cell.layer.addBorder(edge: .bottom, color: .black, thickness: 1)`

Comment: there is space between two cell. it will work with header i think

Answer (score 3):

Since `UICollectionView` doesn't have separators for it's cells you can either switched to a `UITableView` only if it's suitable for your page's design or you can add a separator within the `UICollectionViewCell` by using a `UIView` at the bottom with height of 1. There are also some third party solutions you might try which you can find on GitHub such as these: [Solution 1](https://github.com/ivanbruel/SeparatorCollectionViewFlowLayout), [Solution 2](https://gist.github.com/tomaskraina/1eb291e4717f14ad6e0f8e60ffe9b7d3).

Comment: there is space between two cell. it will work with header i think

Comment: That might work as a workaround but using a `UITableView` would be the better solution since it'll require less coding for separators and same amount of work for creating cells.